# Increase the maximum number of thumbnails per category

Tags: php, model-view-controller, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In the category management, AdminCategories, I can only upload 3 thumbnails.

I want to increase the maximum number which is allowed. In addition I also want to increase the maximum file size.

I don't found the solution in the method `renderForm()` in `AdminCategoriesController.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In classes/helper/HelperForm.php

```
public function generate ()
{
(...)
case 'file':
                            $uploader = new HelperUploader();
                            $uploader->setId(isset($params['id'])?$params['id']:null);
                            $uploader->setName($params['name']);
                            $uploader->setUrl(isset($params['url'])?$params['url']:null);
                            $uploader->setMultiple(isset($params['multiple'])?$params['multiple']:false);
                            $uploader->setUseAjax(isset($params['ajax'])?$params['ajax']:false);
                            $uploader->setMaxFiles(isset($params['max_files'])?$params['max_files']:null);

                            if (isset($params['files']) && $params['files'])
                                $uploader->setFiles($params['files']);
                            elseif (isset($params['image']) && $params['image']) // Use for retrocompatibility                          
                                $uploader->setFiles(array(
                                    0 => array(
                                    'type'       => HelperUploader::TYPE_IMAGE,
                                    'image'      => isset($params['image'])?$params['image']:null,
                                    'size'       => isset($params['size'])?$params['size']:null,
                                    'delete_url' => isset($params['delete_url'])?$params['delete_url']:null
                                )));

                            if (isset($params['file']) && $params['file']) // Use for retrocompatibility                            
                                $uploader->setFiles(array(
                                    0 => array(
                                    'type'       => HelperUploader::TYPE_FILE,
                                    'size'       => isset($params['size'])?$params['size']:null,
                                    'delete_url' => isset($params['delete_url'])?$params['delete_url']:null,
                                    'download_url' => isset($params['file'])?$params['file']:null
                                )));

                            if (isset($params['thumb']) && $params['thumb']) // Use for retrocompatibility                          
                                $uploader->setFiles(array(
                                    0 => array(
                                    'type'       => HelperUploader::TYPE_IMAGE,
                                    'image'      => isset($params['thumb'])?'<img src="'.$params['thumb'].'" alt="'.(isset($params['title']) ? $params['title'] : '').'" title="'.(isset($params['title']) ? $params['title'] : '').'" />':null,
                                )));

                            $uploader->setTitle(isset($params['title'])?$params['title']:null);
                            $params['file'] = $uploader->render();
                        break;
(...)
}
```

You can override this class and set a custom value with setMaxFiles from HelperUploader class.

```
$uploader->setMaxFiles(isset($params['max_files'])?$params['max_files']:null);
```